# What is the best way to collect payment information in a chat interface?

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, desktop-application, chat

We are looking at using a chat-style interface for a sales flow on both desktop and mobile devices. The customer would be able to ask questions about the product, receive a recommendation and pay for the product all in this chat flow.

What is the best way to collect the customer's payment information in this model?

If you have any links to research, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important issue is how to give customer confidence that the payment information they provide is protected. From this perspective, chat window is the *worst* possible option. A person will never feel secure giving out their private data over a chat channel. Even if you say it's absolutely secure.

You may add **Checkout** button to chat window. This button should open a separate screen where user can to provide their payment information. There you may emphasize how the data are protected, e.g. SSL seal, pen-test certification etc. You may keep the chat window on that screen, but it must be visually separated from the payment information delivering a message that payment does not go through the chat.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will be chatting in a window that's over your main ui, 2 things you will need to give the user confidence

- Show security logos
- Showing a clear connection that the payment screen is coming as a result of the chat and is clearly a part of the website/app ui. Showing modal boxes or pop ups is a bad idea in my opinion. The better way would be to take the user to the payment screen while the chat window remains visible. at the same time the loading status of the payment screen could show in the chat window helping the user to make the connection between the chat window and payment screen behind.